# How to enable editing for new inserted row in a GridView while gridview is allowedit = false?

Tags: winforms, gridview, devexpress, xtragrid

I have a GridView control of xtraGrid suite in a form. 
When I open the form for first time it is AllowEdit = false. I want that when I press on add new row link(built in by control) to make editable this only new inserted row. I read that I should use ShowingEditor event but I don't know how.
I wrote this so far but this does not editable the row:

```
private void gridViewNote_ShowingEditor(object sender, System.ComponentModel.CancelEventArgs e)
        {
//this is first tryout  
            //if (gridViewNote.IsNewItemRow(gridViewNote.FocusedRowHandle))// == gridViewNote.GetFocusedDataRow())
            //{
            //    gridColumnStagione.OptionsColumn.AllowEdit = true;
            //}
//second tryout 
            GridView view = sender as GridView;
            SchedeMaterialiDaTaglioDS.SMTAGL_NOTERow currentRow = gridViewNote.GetFocusedDataRow() as SchedeMaterialiDaTaglioDS.SMTAGL_NOTERow;

            SchedeMaterialiDaTaglioDS.SMTAGL_NOTEDataTable changesTable = dsSchMatTaglio.SMTAGL_NOTE.GetChanges() as SchedeMaterialiDaTaglioDS.SMTAGL_NOTEDataTable;
            e.Cancel = !view.IsNewItemRow(view.FocusedRowHandle) &&
                !changesTable.Contains(currentRow);// set.Inserts.Contains(order);

        }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I hope I understood your question. A few simple ways of doing this:

1. Adding a repository item to each column and handle the `ShowingEditor` event, using `e.Cancel` if this is supposed to be read only.
2. Popping up a window/textboxes, letting the user insert values and add the row with values already inserted via code.
3. assigning two different repository items to the same column using `gridView.CustomRowCellEdit` event. like such:

   ```
   RepositoryItemTextEdit rep = new RepositoryItemTextEdit();
   RepositoryItemTextEdit noRep = new RepositoryItemTextEdit();
   noRep.ReadOnly = true;

   private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
   {
       gridView1.AddNewRow();
       justAddedName = true;
       gridView1.RefreshData();
   }

   private void gridView1_CustomRowCellEdit(object sender, DevExpress.XtraGrid.Views.Grid.CustomRowCellEditEventArgs e)
   {
       if (e.Column == colname)
       {
           if (e.RowHandle == gridView1.RowCount - 1 && justAddedName)
           {
               e.RepositoryItem = rep;
           }
           else
           {
               e.RepositoryItem = noRep;
           }
       }
   }
   ```

It's not complete, just a direction to explore.

Hope I helped.